# Security Exception on asp .NET framework 4 using MySql, trust level: Medium

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

Im using VS 2010 MVC3, I set up the web.config to connect to my remote database. When I debug its runs ok, registers, logs in fine. But when I upload it to the host i get this error:

> Security Exception Description: The application attempted to perform
>   an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission please contact your system
>   administrator or change the application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.]
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.CreatePermissionSet()
>   +0    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.DemandPermissions()
>   +38    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.PermissionDemand() +94    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +196
>   MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.GetSchemaVersion(String
>   connectionString) +65
>   MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.CheckSchema(String connectionString,
>   NameValueCollection config) +39
>   MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider.Initialize(String name,
>   NameValueCollection config) +462
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings
>   providerSettings, Type providerType) +419

Im using MySQL Connector Net 6.5.4

Comment: How about the problem [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=449172). Seems to be the same issue due to permissions on trust levels in the host.  Is this a shared host?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a common Problem which a lots of people having.Thats because you build your website in Full trust level.That allows you to do nearly everything by IIS.But a lots of hosting company allows just Medium trust level.So you need to recode necessary parts of your project under Medium trust level.

Open ;

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

folder and open webconfig file,and change line;

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

to

```
<trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />
```

Honestly I don't have a deep knowledge about further step and your assemblies.So I can help that much.

Answer (score 0):

My friend had the same problem. He managed it adding the following setting in the MySql Connection String:

```
includesecurityasserts=true
```